# Ngrx effect - wait 2 seconds and then redirect

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have a ngrx effect in which I'm calling a HTTP method and after I get the response, I want to wait 2 seconds and then redirect to another page

The actual behavior: it redirects without waiting 2 seconds

```
confirmRegistration$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActions.confirmRegistrationAction),
      exhaustMap((action) => {
        return this.authHttpService.confirmRegistration(action.payload).pipe(
          map((res: ConfirmRegistrationResponse) => {
            this.authService.setLocalStorageAuthToken(res.token);
            return AuthActions.confirmRegistrationSuccess(res);
          }),
          tap(interval(2000).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(_ =>
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
          )),
          catchError((error) => of(AuthActions.confirmRegistrationFailure({ error })))
        );
      })
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `debounceTime` operator? Subscribing within `tap` doesn't feel exactly safe, not sure how NgRx would actually handle that.

```typescript
confirmRegistration$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.confirmRegistrationAction),
    exhaustMap((action) => {
      return this.authHttpService.confirmRegistration(action.payload).pipe(
        map((res: ConfirmRegistrationResponse) => {
          this.authService.setLocalStorageAuthToken(res.token);
          return AuthActions.confirmRegistrationSuccess(res);
        }),
        debounceTime(2000),
        tap(() => this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])),
        catchError((error) => of(AuthActions.confirmRegistrationFailure({ error })))
      );
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: This works, but I would use `delay` because `debounce` doesn't actually do anything here, and thus `delay` feels better. In this case, the behavior of the two is the same though.